# Not able to download file using wget

Tags: linux, https, wget

I need to download file from my File cloud in linux but Now I getting below error on linux, If I execute this link on windows then it's download the file.

```
wget  https://cloud.xxxxx.xx/core/downloadfile?filepath=/SHARED /gf/xxxxxxx/my-filename-v6b.box&filename=my-filename-v6b.box&  disposition=attachment
[1] 62347
[2] 62348
$ --2016-01-11 10:45:53--  https://cloud.xxxxx.xx  /core/downloadfile?filepath=/SHARED/ah/xxxxxxxxxxx/my-filename-v6b.box
Resolving cloud.xxxxx.xx (cloud.xxxxx.xx)... xxx.xx.xx.xxx
Connecting to cloud.xxxxx.xx (cloud.xxxxx.xx)|xxx.xxx.xx.xxx|:443...  connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.


[1]-  Done                    wget https://cloud.xxxxx.xx/core/downloadfile?filepath=/SHARED/ah/xxxxxxxxxxx/my-filename-v6b.box
[2]+  Done                    filename=my-filename-v6b.box
```

Comment: Does your URL have spaces in it? Are they supposed to be there? If so, you might have to [URL encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) those. Also, try enclosing your entire URL in single quotes so that bash treats it as a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enclose your URL into single braces:

```
wget 'https://cloud.xxxxx.xx/core/downloadfile?filepath=/SHARED /gf/xxxxxxx/my-filename-v6b.box&filename=my-filename-v6b.box&  disposition=attachment'
```